# Find and replace macro for specific columns only

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working with a macro in Sheets so that special characters are replaced with their HTML equivalents. I need the script to target specific columns, while ignoring others (such as columns that contain URLs).

Here is the previously coded script I am working with:

```
function FindAndReplace() {
  var data_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var num_rows = data_range.getNumRows();
  var num_columns = data_range.getNumColumns();
  var find_replace = {
      "&": "&amp;",
      " - ": " &ndash; ",
      "'": "&#39;",
  }

  Object.keys(find_replace).map(function(find) {
    var replace = find_replace[find];
    for (var row=2; row <= num_rows; row++) {
     for (var col=1; col <= num_columns; col++) {
        var value = data_range.getCell(row, col).getValue();
        if (data_range.getCell(row, col).getFormula()) {continue;}
        try {
           value = value.replace(find, replace);
           data_range.getCell(row, col).setValue(value);
        }
        catch (err) {continue;}
     }
  }
 });
}
```

This script is working, but it's making the changes for the entire sheet. I would also ideally like to have the script ignore any HTML codes that contain an **&** (eg. `&amp;`)

The specific issue is with this line in the script:

```
for (var col=1; col <= num_columns; col++) {
```

I have been trying to edit it to select only columns 1, 3 and 5 but it errors out. It currently only works as it is now. All I want it to do is select specific columns while ignoring the rest

I am not very familiar with JavaScript so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Google Apps Script uses JavaScript, not Java. Please show what you tried to adapt your script to your actual goal and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Sorry, the specific issue is with this line in the script, "for (var col=1; col <= num_columns; col++) {" 
I have been trying to edit it to select only columns 1, 3 and 5 but it errors out. It currently only works as it is now. All I want it to do is select specific columns while ignoring the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to replace the values using the object of `find_replace` in the specific columns of the active sheet.
- You don't want to replace the cells which have the formula.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- About `This script is working, but it's making the changes for the entire sheet.`, in your script, `var num_columns = data_range.getNumColumns()` is used for the condition of loop. And, the loop is run from 1 to `num_columns` for each column. I thought that this is the reason of your issue.
- And, in your script, your goal of `I would also ideally like to have the script ignore any HTML codes that contain an & (eg. &amp;)` cannot be achieved. When `&amp;` is found, `&` of `&amp;` is also replaced with `&amp;`.
- In this answer, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose to the following flow.

  1. Preapare the target columns as an array.
  2. Create an array from the object of `find_replace`.
  3. Replace the values.
     3a. Replace the values to other unique values.
     3b. Replace the keys to the values.
     3c. Replace the unique values to the values.
- Replacing values are run using TextFinder.

  - I thought that when TextFinder is used in your situation, the process cost of the script might be able to be reduced.

When above flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function FindAndReplace2() {
  // 1. Preapare the target columns as an array.
  var targetColumns = [2, 5]; // 2 and 5 means the column "B" and "E", respectively.
  var find_replace = {
      "&": "&amp;",
      "-": "&amp;",
      "'": "&#39;",
  }

  // 2. Create an array from the object of `find_replace`.
  var ar = Object.entries(find_replace).map(([k, v]) => ({k: k, v: v, u: Utilities.getUuid().replace(/-/g, "")}));
  
  // 3. Replace the values.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  targetColumns.forEach(c => {
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, c, sheet.getLastRow());
    ar.forEach(({k, v, u}) => {
      // 3a. Replace the values to other unique values.
      range.createTextFinder(v).replaceAllWith(u);

      // 3b. Replace the keys to the values.
      range.createTextFinder(k).replaceAllWith(v);

      // 3c. Replace the unique values to the values.
      range.createTextFinder(u).replaceAllWith(v);
    });
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)